JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException on inserting domain with id
I am using Springboot 4.5.8 with Hibernate JPA interacting with Postgresql DBMS. I am prefetching ID from DB sequence for table workflow_testcase and using it for insertion. This code is working fine, but for few cases, I am getting exception like:
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find abc.xyz.projectname.testcase.domain.WorkflowTestCase with id 222016; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find abc.xyz.projectname.testcase.domain.WorkflowTestCase with id 222016

on executing the method:-
@Transactional
WorkflowTestCase insertTestCase(Long id, String name) {
    WorkflowTestCase workflowTestCase = new WorkflowTestCase();
    workflowTestCase.setId(id);
    workflowTestCase.setName(name);

    workflowTestCaseDB = workflowTestCaseRepository.save(workflowTestCase);
    return workflowTestCaseDB;
}

This leads to rolling back of transaction, thus losing data
The entity is:
@Entity
@Table(name = "workflow_testcase")
@ToString
public class WorkflowTestCase {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Testcase name should not be blank")
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

Table schema:
workflow_test=# \d+ workflow_testcase
                                                                     Table "public.workflow_testcase"
           Column            |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                          | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('workflow_testcase_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name                        | character varying(1024)     |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "workflow_testcase_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Access method: heap



could you also parse the table schema of workflow_testcase?
